# Adjust Y position of a div after clicking the id

Tags: jquery, html

I have a website that works with tabs. After clicking on a link, it is sent to another tab referencing its id. But I would like to adjust the position y after clicking the id. Can anyone help me please?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".speaker").click(function() {
      $('.tab-last')[0].click();
      window.scrollBy(0, 100);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to position the window to have the tabs be at the top of the page after clicking or triggering a click on a tab. If that is the case:

```
$('.speaker').on('click', (function() {//Use $.on for bindings these days
  var $tabLast = $('.tab-last').eq(0);

  $tabLast.click();

  //Scroll the window to the element you want to be at the top
  //20 gives you a little padding, can change this
  $('html, body').css('scrollTop', ($tabLast.offset().top - 20));
});
```

Or if you want to **animate** the window scrolling and focus on the element after animation is complete:

```
$('.speaker').on('click', (function() {//Use $.on for bindings these days
  var $tabLast = $('.tab-last').eq(0);

  $tabLast.click();

  //Scroll the window to the element you want to be at the top
  $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: ($tabLast.offset().top - 20)
    }, 
    500,
    function() {
        $tabLast.eq(0).focus();
    });
});
```